# function for, if and three conditions. and there are some NA in my data set

Tags: r, function, loops

**Hello everyone!
Here is my code:**

```
f1 <- function(x){
    if(x > 10){
      z = 1
    } else if (x < 10 && x >0) {
      z=2
    } else {
      z=3} 
      return(z)
    } 

    r <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,1:96)
    s <- numeric(100)
    for(i in 1:length(s)){
      s[i] <- f1(r)
    }
```

**ERROR:**

> Error in if (x > 10) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In if (x > 10) { :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

**What I need:**
I have a data set 'r'. I need to create a function or loop for judge my data set. Then put the result in 's'.

**'s' is somethings like this:**

```
3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 1 1 1 1 1 1....
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either replace NA before hand, i.e.

```
r[is.na(r)] <- -1
ifelse(r > 10, 1, ifelse(r <10 & r > 0, 2, 3))
#[1] 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1...

#or include !is.na(r) in every condition, i.e.

ifelse(r > 10 & !is.na(r), 1, ifelse(r <10 & r > 0 & !is.na(r), 2, 3))
#[1] 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's really helpful.